# unable to run OpenFOAM docker image

Tags: docker, openfoam

I'm trying to use [the OpenFOAM docker image](https://www.openfoam.com/download/install-binary-windows.php). I installed everything correctly and when I try to run `OpenFOAM_Start` I get the error:

> Started machines may have new IP addresses. You may need to re-run the `docker-machine env` command.
>
> Error response from daemon: No such container: of_1712
>
> Error: failed to start containers: of_1712
>
> Error: No such container: of_1712
>
> Stopping "default"...
>
> Machine "default" was stopped.

Then I ran `docker-machine env` command and I got the error:

> Error checking TLS connection: Host is not running

I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it.

P.S. Hopefully this is not off-topic. Please let me know if I should ask this question in a different stackexchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution but I'm still not sure what the error above mean. As indicated in the OpenFOAM installation guide, right after installation of the docker image you should run the:

> "OF_Create_Env"
>    shortcut on the Desktop. A shell will open and close automatically,
>    completing setup of the user working environment. This step is mandatory
>    only on the first occasion of OpenFOAM for Windows installation.

Then you can run `OpenFOAM_Start` again and it just works.